# How to solve this trigonometric equation further?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the sum of the roots of the equation
$$
\sin (2\cos x - \sqrt{3}) = 0
$$

belonging to the segment

$$
A_m = [2m\pi; ~ \frac{\pi}{2} + (2m+2)\pi]
$$

where $m = -4$. Round the number to two decimal places if necessary.

**my incomplete solution:**

> $$2\cos x - \sqrt 3 = k\pi$$
>
> $$k = 0 \text{ fits}$$
> $$k = 1$$
> $$ 2\cos x = pi + \sqrt3 = 3.14 + 1.73> 2$$ - not suitable. For
> larger $k$, it is even worse ...
>
> $$k = -1$$
> $$2\cos x = -3.14 + 1.73 = -1.41$$ Hmm Suitable unfortunately.
> Smaller ones won't fit
>
> This means that there are 2 options
>
> 1. $$cos x = 0$$ $$x = \pi / 2 + 2n\pi$$ The segment $$[-8\pi, \pi / 2 - 6\pi]$$ 2
>    roots hit $$-8\pi + \pi / 2$$ and $$-6\pi + \pi / 2$$
> 2. $$\cos x = -0.705$$ (coincidence with the root of 2 is random here) But
>    approximately you can say $$x = + -2\pi / 3 + 2n\pi$$

I have a problem with subsequent calculations, it lies in the fact that I do not understand how and what to calculate

I would be grateful if you could solve this problem to the end with an explanation

Comment: Note that $2 \cos (x+\frac{\pi}{3}) = \cos x - \sqrt{3}  \; \boldsymbol{\sin x} $

Comment: @A.J. yes, I already understood that the game wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2\cos x-\sqrt3=k\pi$$ is possible with $k=-1$ and $k=0$.

Now we have the solutions

$$x=2n\pi\pm\arccos\frac{\sqrt3}2$$ and $$x=2n\pi\pm\arccos\frac{\sqrt3-\pi}2.$$

As solutions are requested in the range $\left[-8\pi,-8\pi+\dfrac52\pi\right]$ you need to find suitable values of $n$. Start with $n=-4$ (which gives two solutions) and increase $n$ until the options become too large.

[image]

Comment: you have the wrong range because it turns out [-8pi, pi / 2 - 6pi]

Comment: and it seems to me that your two solutions are wrong too
$$cos x = b$$
$$x = + -arccos b + 2pi n$$
There are only 2 solutions on the circle

Comment: @марат: in my country, $\frac12-6$ and $-8+\frac52$ are equal.

Comment: @марат: and the four solutions come from the two values of $k$. Read twice before commenting.

Comment: sorry,about the range I was wrong really
we also have these expressions are equal

Comment: we got a disagreement with you on the decision, what is the final answer you got?

Comment: i solved and got the answer -106.29 , did you get the same answer?

Comment: @марат: I did not solve to the end, as this is an easy part. Your answer is clearly not in the range.

Comment: I think that the computational part is one of the difficult ones, I will add an answer where I will give a solution method based on your data, say what is wrong then or better decide too and name the correct answer

Comment: which root of five is missing?

Comment: @марат: there is no "root of five missing". I guess that you don't follow my instructions.

Comment: I follow your instructions, I just do not fully understand them
I realized that my mistake is that only 3 roots are obtained $$(-35pi / 6); (-37pi / 6); (-47pi / 6)$$, instead of 5

Comment: @марат: sorry,  did not realize that you were giving the sum of the roots.

Comment: @марат: what values of $n$ did you use ?

Comment: based on YOUR solution,$$ 2cosX-√3 = 0$$ on the interval [-8pi; -5.5pi] has three roots, this is for n = 0. And for n = -1 the equation $$2cosx = √3-pi$$ two more. total 5

Comment: then the answer is -106.29

Comment: Well, look at your schedule. Between the green and red vertical lines, the graph crosses the Ox axis at five points
this means that the equation is correct and the answer is also correct

Comment: @марат: $n=0$ and $n=-1$ don't work. You should start from $n=-4$ !

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

For real $x,$

$$-2-\sqrt3\le2\cos x-\sqrt3\le2-\sqrt3=\dfrac1{2+\sqrt3}$$

$\dfrac1{2+\sqrt3}<\pi\implies k<1$

Again, $2+\sqrt3<2\pi\implies k>-2$

So, what are the possible values of $k?$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: k=0, k = -1......

Comment: 2cos x - sqrt (3) = pi * k
k = 0 fits
k = 1 2cosx = pi + sqrt (3) = 3.14 + 1.73> 2 - not suitable. For larger k, it is even worse ...
k = -1 2cosx = -3.14 + 1.73 = -1.41 Hmm Suitable unfortunately. Smaller ones won't fit
This means that there are 2 options
1) cosx = 0 x = pi / 2 + 2pi * n. The segment [-8pi, pi / 2 - 6pi]. 2 roots hit -8pi + pi / 2 and -6pi + pi / 2
2) cosx = -0.705 (coincidence with the root of 2 is random here) But approximately you can say x = + -2pi / 3 + 2pi * n

Comment: i added this  my calculations in question

Comment: @марат, If $\cos x=0,$   $$\sin(-\sqrt3)=0$$  right?

Comment: no..............................

Comment: the problem is almost solved (see a partial solution in the question), but not solved, how can you complete its solution further?

Answer (score 0):

based on the data given by the user **Yves Daoust**, I solved this problem

> 5 roots fall into the specified interval from the graph.
>
> the interval [-8pi, pi / 2 - 6pi] is divided into two: [-8pi, - 6pi]
> and [-6pi, - 6pi + pi / 2].
>
> The first interval will have 4 roots:
>
> $$x = pi / 6 - 8pi$$
>
> $$x = -pi / 6 - 6pi$$
>
> $$x = -7pi + arccos ((pi-sqrt3) / 2)$$
>
> $$x = -7pi - arccos ((pi-sqrt3) / 2)$$
>
> The second interval [-6pi, - 6pi + pi / 2] corresponds on the unit
> circle to the first coordinate quarter, so $$x = pi / 6 - 6pi$$ will get
> here.
>
> The sum of these five roots is $$pi (-8-6-7-7-6 + 1/6) = - pi * 203/6 =
> > -106, 29.$$

to check the result

[image]